# are there any tools to generate css3 styles for shapes

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am looking for some tools that generates css3 style for the shape we draw. It should be something like a drawing program. Say I draw a rounded rectangle i get the styles for it.
It can be drawing program or online tools.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS transitions?